# use htaccess to add www with https support

Tags: apache, http, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

There are a lot of code examples for using .htaccess to add www to a url but they are usually confined to using http. does anybody have an example of how to get it to work in both cases?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Sure:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The second condition checks if the *HTTPS* environment variable (either `on` or `off`) is set to `on` and captures the appended `s` that is then available with `%1`. If it doesn’t match, `%1` is just an empty string.

Comment: @Gumbo, should that second line be: %{HTTPS} ?

Comment: I am facing issue with adding double "www" within the URL ex. "https://www.www.domainname.com" when the user type URL in the domain as "http://www.domainname.com"

Answer (score 0):

use this code in .htaccess and it will add both https and www

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
    RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```