# (Yet another) Beautiful way to remove www via rewrite in .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Yes, I know this question has been asked 1000 times before... here is the difference...

I found this answer on StackOverflow to ADD the "www" here:
[use htaccess to add www with https support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097542/use-htaccess-to-add-www-with-https-support)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

And it is the most beautiful and graceful solution I have ever seen:

- It works
- It doesn't need to be changed to be used for a specific domain
- It addresses both HTTP and HTTPS connections
- Its only 3 lines

So, my question is simple. Can someone help me adapt this code to work in the opposite direction? (To remove the WWW from web addresses and address all the above points)?

I believe that between the above (and hopefully below) solutions, we will have the www rewrite to rule them all!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%2://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Taken from the Drupal 7 `.htaccess` file, works like a charm. Updated a bit to add the https check.

Comment: Really cute, but doesn't work on LiteSpped. Seems like LiteSpeed only sets %N variables from last RewriteCond. See two line solution below.

Comment: I tried to sign up at litespeedtech.com to report the bug, but got a 403 error. Can an existing member report the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I got problem with above answer, it started to redirect to `http://http:///`

So I did some changes and this is code which worked for me (on apache2 Ubuntu server, VPS server) to redirect from http://www.example.com to  http://example.com **(www to non www)** AND from http://example.com to https://example.com **(http to https)**.

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$
    RewriteRule ^ http%2://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: @bummi Thanks for editing answer. Mistakenly I put real url here. I will follow standards next time.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version that is only two lines, and works on both Apache and LiteSpeed

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s-%{HTTP_HOST} ^(on(s)|offs)-www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http%2://%3/$1 [L,R=301]
```