# HTACCESS add WWW with HTTPS redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

Currently my htaccess code is

```
#add www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]


#send all traffic to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

This works when following urls are entered

```
1. https://example.com -> https://www.example.com
2. http://example.com -> https://www.example.com
3. http://www.example.com -> https://www.example.com
4. https://example.com -> https://www.example.com
5. https://example.com/somepage -> https://www.example.com/somepage
6. http://www.example.com/somepage -> https://www.example.com/somepage
```

But it doesn't work when both https and www is not present while trying to access some page, instead it redirect to strange url

```
7. http://example.com/somepage -> https://www.example.com/https://example.com/somepage
```

Comment: does not work if you type https://example.com (or copy-paste example.com to a tab open to some other https address), here is the correct answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2097565/3198388

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace your current code by this one

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Note: maybe you'll have to clear your browser's cache to see it working for `http://example.com/somepage`